# Modfification history in webdash board unseen?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am using my ccnet which is configured with the clear case
and everything is working fine as expected,but i am unable to see
anything in the "ViewProjectModificationHistory".whenever i click this
tab,i see a message which tells that :"No history Data found, make
sure you use the modificationHistory Publisher for this
project".Infact i had added  under the  tag.And to my
suprise,when i open this same link in the other persons system,it
opens well and fine and see all the modification history recorded.

So can anyone please tell me what could be this issue and how can it
be resolved?

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

You should check your build history file. This will contain the XML data that feeds these reports. In particular, check the modifications/modification nodes to see if they are populated or not.

My guess is that the modifications are not there - so there may be nothing to display.

Another gotcha I have caught myself doing is not actually checking that there was in fact changes committed since the last time I built a project.